# Ember-CLI: Cannot find module 'broccoli-static-compiler'Error: Cannot find module 'broccoli-static-compiler'

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Anyone know what this error means? Most important: how to fix?

`Cannot find module 'broccoli-static-compiler'Error: Cannot find module 'broccoli-static-compiler'`

This happened today after installing ember-cli new project and trying to run `ember server`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means `ember serve` can't find the Node.js package `broccoli-static-compiler`. Broccoli provides the build pipeline for Ember CLI projects, `broccoli-static-compiler` is a Broccoli plugin that copies files as-is to the build output.

I cannot reproduce this with Ember CLI `0.0.28` and `0.0.29`, this package *should* be available in `YOURPROJECT/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/`. Which version of Ember CLI do you have installed? (`ember --version`)

You could try installing `broccoli-static-compiler` yourself locally for your new project by running `npm install --save-dev broccoli-static-compiler` from the project directory.

Comment: I should have the latest version I just set it up yesterday... However, I realized I used SUDO to do the npm install so I wonder if that caused a bug?

Comment: If you did `sudo npm install` in your project directory, then yes, that sounds like a probably cause. Use `sudo npm` only when installing things globally, like `npm install -g ember-cli`.

Comment: Try `sudo rm -rf node_modules` in your project directory and run `npm install` again as a normal user.

Comment: yeah, my sudo caused a bunch of cascading errors... after gooing throught them one at a time, i found that on top of it all I did a custom bootstrap/sass integration that got botched.  Ill try again later... thanks

Answer (score 5):

## Broccoli Static Compiler

(1) Install the required broccoli extensions:

```
npm install --save-dev broccoli-static-compiler
npm install --save-dev broccoli-merge-trees
```

(2) Edit **Brocfile.js**.

Remove or comment this line:

```
module.exports = app.toTree();
```

Add (and modify to suit):

```
// require the static compiler
var pickFiles = require('broccoli-static-compiler');
// choose the static files - path usually: 'vendor/module/dist'
var iCanHasFiles = pickFiles('path/to/files', {
    srcDir: '/',
    // 'files' is optional for choosing some of the srcDir's content.
    // NB: Do not include directories here!
    files: ['file.js', 'file.css', 'file.woff'],
    destDir: '/assets/icanhasfiles'
});

// Merge the iCanHasFiles with the ember app tree
var mergeTrees = require('broccoli-merge-trees');
module.exports = mergeTrees([app.toTree(), iCanHasFiles]);
```

(3) Other JavaScript files can be added via this file too. They *must* be inserted above the module.exports call in **Brocfile.js**.

```
// after "bower install --save bower-module-name" (bower.io/search for name).
app.import('vendor/module/file.js');
```

## Ember-cli and Bootstrap

(A) Instructions for creating new project **app-project** with Bootstrap inclusion:

```
ember new app-project
cd app-project
bower install --save bootstrap-sass-official
npm install --save-dev broccoli-sass
mv app/styles/app.css app/styles/app.scss
```

(B) Open **app/styles/app.scss**, and change the import path:

```
@import 'vendor/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap';
```

(C) To include Glyphicons font, open **Brocfile.js**:

```
// import the necessary modules:
var pickFiles = require('broccoli-static-compiler');
var mergeTrees = require('broccoli-merge-trees');

// at the bottom of the file, replace the "module.exports" line with:
// module.exports = app.toTree();

// Put the bootstrap fonts in the place that the bootstrap css expects to find them.
var bootstrapFonts = pickFiles('vendor/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/fonts/bootstrap', {
    srcDir: '/',
    destDir: '/assets/bootstrap'
});

// Merge the bootstrapFonts with the ember app tree
var mergeTrees = require('broccoli-merge-trees');
module.exports = mergeTrees([
    app.toTree(),
    bootstrapFonts
]);
```

(D) Alternatively, for classic glyphicons (bootstrap 2.3 etc):

```
// if using glyphicons instead (bootstrap 2.3 etc):
var glyphicons = pickFiles('vendor/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/fonts/bootstrap', {
    srcDir: '/',
    files: [
        'glyphicons-halflings-regular.*',
    ],
    destDir: '/assets/bootstrap'
});

// Merge the glyphicons with the ember app tree
module.exports = mergeTrees([
    app.toTree(),
    glyphicons
]);
```

Comment: nice!  I will give this a go!